# How to generify data binding layout inflation?

Tags: android

I wanna make a BaseFragment. For this, I have to use ViewDataBinding and ViewModel. using generic, I can use variable but not static field. For example I have to Inflate writing this code "FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false) ". So I tried this code "T.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)" but got some error. Also ViewModel is like this.
How can I make this code to BaseCode?

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T: ViewDataBinding, M : ViewModel> : DaggerFragment(){

    abstract val layoutId : T
    private lateinit var  binding : T


    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel by viewModels<M> { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


        binding = T.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to abstract out the particular ViewDataBinding, however, it would require to provide a layout resource reference for each concrete fragment implementation:

```
protected abstract val layoutResource: Int

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private val viewModel by viewModels<M> { viewModelFactory }

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutResource, container, false).apply {
        viewmodel = viewModel
    }
    return binding.root
}
```